# How do I install Ubuntu on a SSD with HDD for data?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have bought a new computer with a 128GB SSD and a 750GB HDD, and I'd like to install Ubuntu 13.10 O.S., hardware drivers and programs that I will use more often on the SSD and data on the HDD Disk (film, video, photo.. Etc ..). It makes sense?

How is it possible for me to do this?

Comment: Is computer UEFI and do you want UEFI or BIOS? Will you be installing Windows? I suggest gpt partitioning as Ubuntu can boot from UEFI if you have a 300MB efi partition near beginning of drive or boot with BIOS from gpt if you have a tiny 1 or 2MB bios_grub partion. But Windows will only boot from gpt partitioned drive with UEFI. So some planning on systems and how you may want to boot is required to plan correct partitioning and partitions.

Comment: BIOS. I will not install windows. I just want ubuntu for my notebook

Answer (score 3):

Install Linux to the SSD (100GB is much more room than needed) after configuring your machine's BIOS to set the SSD as sda and the HDD as sdb, and make the SSD (sda) the boot drive.

When the installation process comes to partition, set up both drives with the default filesystem ext4 - and swap goes at the back of the HDD as per normal. You can also revised that after installation ends with the *Gparted* utility of Ubuntu.

Leave about 10%-20% of the space on the SSD unallocated, for as the SSD ages, specific addresses will fail, and the SSD will automatically block those and replace them with addresses in the unallocated space. Also, this “Over-provisioning” boosts an SSD’s sustained write performance by allocating temporary space as discussed at http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/5822/sandisk-x210-256gb-business-class-ssd-exploring-overprovisioning/index.html . The ext4 partition on the SSD should be about 80-90% of the total space, or 103GB-115GB, with about 13GB-25GB left unallocated, outside that partition.

After installation, modify the filesystem by editing /etc/fstab to put /tmp /var and /home on sdb along with swap, and add the **,noatime** parameter to sda , then save and reboot.

The purpose of **noatime** is to disable timestamping of file reads which cuts down the number of I/O ops. Should a program need timestamping then remove **noatime** which in Ubuntu will default to **relatime** instead which keeps the timestamps more or less accurate with only a slight uptick in I/O.

A good detailed article on the subject can be found at https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization and examples of what /etc/fstab should look like may be seen at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD#noatime_Mount_Flag and at http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=76921

Comment: Didn't get the part "Leave about 10% of the space on the SSD unallocated, for as the SSD ages " any helpful links ?

Comment: In practice, how can I do this operations? Are explained in the link of wiki?

Comment: Ubuntu does relatime by default, there' usually no need to add it explicitly.