# Putting Ubuntu on an SSD and Files on an HDD

Tags: partitioning, system-settings, storage

I am installing Ubuntu on a home theater PC. I want to put Plex Media Server on it so I can stream my digital content to all my devices. I have an SSD and an HDD in the build. I want to install Ubuntu and Plex on the SSD and put all the media on the HDD. I am in the setup under the "Something Else" when it comes time to choose how to install Ubuntu. I need the steps to correctly partition stuff. Please note I am not experienced with system files, storage, and Ubuntu.

Comment: Is system newer UEFI or older BIOS based? Then if UEFI do you want UEFI or BIOS? I would basically put all of Ubuntu on SSD and use hard drive as a data partition for storing all the media files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to manually put the files on the HDD, but it is doable.

1. Remove the HDD from the computer.
2. Install Ubuntu and your media server.
3. Put the HDD back in, and format it with the ext4 filesystem format.
4. Just store all of your files on the HDD as if it were any other hard drive.

That's the simplest way, in which you don't have to create any specialized partitions.  More complex ways are available if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

What you should to do is put your **root /** partition on you SSD. You're **/home** and **swap** will need to be installed on the HDD. However, this will not allow you to install Plex on your SSD. The reason you for this is you are trying to limit your read/write cycles on your SSD to extend it's life.

Here is a very good resource for detailed instructions: [How do I install Ubuntu on a SSD with HDD for data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377229/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-ssd-with-hdd-for-data)